# New JSESSIONID cookie is generated upon entering different Struts namespace

Tags: java, session, cookies, struts2, jsessionid

Our web app has two different namespaces. For the purposes of this question, they will be referred to as `/packageOne` and `/packageTwo`.

While accessing Struts actions within `/packageOne`, everything works as designed as the `JSESSIONID` does not change.

On a **specific type of computer** (*corporate notebook computer belong to an employee of a particular department*), the `JSESSIONID` changes upon going to a Struts action in `/packageTwo`. In addition, other properties within the cookie disappear along with the change, so it seems that a new cookie has been created in place. Going back to a Struts action within `/packageOne` reverses this change, reinstating the previous `JSESSIONID` cookie.

From our understanding, a new `JSESSIONID` is created whenever a particular user session does not already exist. In this case, we are wondering why a switch of namespaces meant that the existing user session was no longer applicable and thus requiring the creation of a new `JSESSIONID`.

**EDIT:** This is what our `web.xml` looks like. It is pretty much the default one.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Struts Project Name</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**EDIT 2:** This is how we found out that the `JSESSIONID` changed

- We opened the webapp in Chrome and activated the Developer Console.
- Upon the login form of our webapp, which is situated in `/packageOne` namespace, we are taken to the main home page which is another Struts action within the same namespace `/packageOne`
- We switched to the Resources tab, expanded the Cookies item in the resource tree and clicked on the cookie that was named after our domain.
- In the table to the right of the resource tree, we see `JSESSIONID` as the name of one of the rows and noted that value. We also noted that there are other fields such as `csrf_token`, `APISID`, `HSID`, `NID` and so on.
- Upon proceeding to a Struts action in a separate namespace, namely `/packageTwo`, we noted in the Developer Console that the cookie that bore the same name now had a different `JSESSIONID` value (in the Value column) and that most of the other fields are missing except for one, which I forgot which it was.

I understand that it is unclear what we are asking for. We are trying to find out the causes of such an **anomaly** as under our test environment, staging and many other production environments for this same webapp, this does not happen at all (the `JSESSIONID` and other fields in the cookie remain the same even after switching to a Struts action in `/packageTwo`).

**EDIT 3:** More information about the problematic environment in which this anomaly occurred:

- It is a corporate notebook PC, an IBM Thinkpad.
- It was connected to the corporate WiFi.
- It belonged to Human Resources.
- We could not reproduce the same anomaly on a corporate notebook PC that is of similar model and make (IBM Thinkpad) that was connected to the same corporate WiFi, the difference being that it belonged to an employee from the IT department.
- We could, however, reproduce the same anomaly on a different PC belonging to the same employee, and the problem was reported by other employees in the department as well.

Comment: You can elaborate more about how jsessionid changes and how did you know that, from the context of your question is unclear what are you asking.

Comment: Noted. I have added more details. Thank you for responding!

Comment: if this only on one PC then you can forget it, otherwise it's more like SU question rather than SO. If you want to post your question here you should demonstrate that you understand programming.

Comment: Sounds like a [Session Fixation Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), or something similar. If it happens on one PC only, it's evident that the problem is there... I'd carefully check it for malware and/or traces of suspicious activity. I'd also move this question to [**security**.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/). +1 for the effort BTW

Comment: thank you Roman and Andrea. I am a programmer hence this was the first place I thought of posting this question to.

To answer both of you, it's not just on one PC, but an entire class of PCs from the same department's employees. We have been suspecting a long while that it is a side-effect of corporate security policies, but can't put a proper theory on it yet until we sought more information from kind souls on the web such as you guys.

Comment: @derfshaya interesting one +1

Comment: `We have been suspecting a long while that it is a side-effect of corporate security policies`: if all their PCs are afflicted, then you are probably right, there is something in them, or in their network, or in the datapath, responsible for *things going south*. I'd start with a brand new PC in their network (manually installed, not cloned like the others). If it works, then start adding their softwares and settings, and retry after each one, until it stops working. When it stops, you've found the culprit. This is a job that *they* must do, however, not you (unless officially in charge).